# Calculate driving distance and time from 2 lat/lon points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, time, driving

I'm researching a way to calculate driving time and distance for 2 latitude and longitude points?

I'm unable to use any 3rd party controls or maps.  If possible it has to all be generated locally to my machine.  I'm working with very restricted data.

Can ArcGIS do this and if so what do I need to do this in a batch?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Route analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004700000045000000) if you have the Network Analyst extension. Input your stops, solve the route, the results will have distance and time values.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the Network Analyst extension a separate add on?  Do I have to purchase it?

Comment: Correct, it is an extension. http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst free trial available.

Comment: Thank you.  To do the routing do you know if I am sending data from my local computer to one of ArcGIS servers?   I am not allowed to let the data leave my local computer so I have to do it all locally.

Comment: Not sure, we have our concurrent Network Analyst license hosted on a local server.

Comment: The data never leaves your local computer. But note that you'll need to have a route-able road network in order for Network Analyst to know where the roads are, how long they are, and what speed limits apply. Network Analyst supplies the algorithms, not the underlying datasets