# Calculating drive time in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, point, qgis-2, time, drive-time-areas

I have more than 3000 points that spread in in a very big area. I need to find all the points (blue) that are in distance of 50 minute drive time, from the stores (green stars). I want to calculate it in automate way on all the points, and not each point separately.

Not all the stores located on the road layer (brown colored lines are from the Open Street Map).

I read

- [Creating drive time polygons using Open Source tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools)
- [Calculate driving distance and time from 2 lat/lon points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157734/calculate-driving-distance-and-time-from-2-lat-lon-points?rq=1)

but didn't found any solution.

I also tried to use the *Road graph* plugin-with no success.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to download the OSM tools plugin for which you will need a Google API key.

Once downloaded select the accessibility tab, choose your options (as seen in the image below) and then select your stores layer.

[image]

You can then do a select by location tool to select all of your points that fall within the 50 minute isochrone.

Comment: AGW94 the "mins" = minute?

Comment: Yes they do equal minutes.

Comment: ok-thanks. I don't understand how to operate the tool- when i insert the layer that i want to measure distances from it (start location) to another layer (end location)- i get unreasonable result

Comment: Please could you elaborate?

Comment: 1. i want to read more about this tool   2. what layer i choose in the start location- "from layer" field and  what layer i choose in the end location-   "from layer" field ?

Comment: AWGIS, i don't know how to use this tool- can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

OSM Tools has been deprecated, replaced by ORS Tools